# Migration of local Django project to pythonanywhere throws incorrect timezone error when running manage.py

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I have a local Django project that runs fine. I am following the instructions from pythonanywhere (https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/). I set up a virtualenv and made sure my Django versions match.

When I get to the point of running `./manage.py migrate` I get a permission denied error: `bash: ./manage.py: Permission denied`

If I instead try to run `python3 manage.py migrate` I get a timezone setting error

Bash console output

```
(Tooling-virtualenv) 09:31 ~/Tooling/Tooling (master)$ python3 manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/Tooling-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/Tooling-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 325, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/Tooling-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/Tooling-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/Tooling-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 189, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Incorrect timezone setting: %s" % self.TIME_ZONE)
ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting: America\Los_Angeles
```

pythonanywhere error log

```
2019-11-26 01:20:11,190: Error running WSGI application
2019-11-26 01:20:11,200: ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting: America\Los_Angeles
2019-11-26 01:20:11,200:   File "/var/www/username_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 54, in <module>
2019-11-26 01:20:11,200:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2019-11-26 01:20:11,200: 
2019-11-26 01:20:11,200:   File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/Tooling-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2019-11-26 01:20:11,200:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2019-11-26 01:20:11,201: 
2019-11-26 01:20:11,201:   File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/Tooling-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2019-11-26 01:20:11,201:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2019-11-26 01:20:11,201: 
2019-11-26 01:20:11,201:   File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/Tooling-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
2019-11-26 01:20:11,202:     self._setup(name)
2019-11-26 01:20:11,202: 
2019-11-26 01:20:11,202:   File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/Tooling-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
2019-11-26 01:20:11,202:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2019-11-26 01:20:11,202: 
2019-11-26 01:20:11,202:   File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/Tooling-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 189, in __init__
2019-11-26 01:20:11,203:     raise ValueError("Incorrect timezone setting: %s" % self.TIME_ZONE)
```

I have confirmed that 'America/Los_Angeles' exists under /usr/share/zoneinfo. I tried changing the casing, and I tried changing to 'US/Pacific'. Neither of these yielded any different results I also updated my pythonanywhere timezone to 'America/Los_Angeles' to match.

I'm at a loss for what to try next besides maybe starting my Django project from scratch, and importing the files I need.

Comment: According to the error, you had `America\Los_Angeles` rather than `America/Los_Angeles` -- note the direction of the slash.  The "permission denied" just means that the file `manage.py` doesn't have execute permissions (I'm guessing you uploaded it from a Windows machine or something like that?).  You can fix that by running `chmod +x manage.py` -- then the command `./manage.py migrate` will work without `python3` at the start.

Comment: @GilesThomas thank you! I was able to circumvent the issue, but the direction of the slash was definitely the culprit. You're correct that I uploaded from a Windows machine. Which is also why I didn't have any issues with the slash locally. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by commenting out the timezone from settings.py and adding the following to the top of my WSGI.

```
import time

os.environ["TZ"] = "America/Los_Angeles"
time.tzset()
```

Answer (score 0):

add this top of WSGI:

```
import time

os.environ["TZ"] = "America/Los_Angeles"
time.tzset()
```

then run this command on base:

```
chmod +x manage.py
```

then the command `./manage.py migrate` will work.